# How to open a local pdf file through chrome driver?

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to open a local pdf file using chrome driver?
I have tried this

```
driver().switchTo().window("file://C:\Users\ashok\Downloads\fileToRead.pdf")
```

which is not working for me. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Local files can be opened with simple `driver.get()`.
Also the slashes should be corrected.
Try this:

```java
driver().get("C://Users/ashok/Downloads/fileToRead.pdf")
```

Comment: yes it worked. thanks, but is there any other method to do the same, because i need the   switch back to the previous url in the next step.

Comment: 1) This is not what you asked in the original question 2) you can always open the web page regularly back with `driver.get(url)` but this will probably not save the changes previously made there 3) You can create additional `driver` object to open the downloaded files while staying with the first `driver` on the web page to keep the session flow.

Comment: sorry, i thought that will work for all cases,